# Bootstrap validator - submitting fom without correct validation

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good Day!

I have a [contact form](http://testurl321.site50.net/validatorTest/) that is using [bootstrap validator](http://www.bootstrapvalidator.com).
I am able to get the (in)validation of the fields to show up as expected, but it does not seem like the submit button is "respecting" the (in)validation before submitting - the fields does not HAVE to be validated in order for the form to be submitted. I am using ajax in order to submit the form without realoding the entire page.

The ajax code should be located in the mashup.js file, of my [contact test page!](http://testurl321.site50.net/validatorTest/)

(in case you have not already noticed it, I am a n00b - and would really appreciate the help:)

**UPDATE:** (This is the current code)

**.html**

```
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- Website Title & Description for Search Engine purposes -->
        <title>Contact Form</title>

        <!-- Mobile viewport optimized -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

        <!-- Content-Type -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="includes/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="includes/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Responsive Navigator -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/nav/responsive-nav.css">
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/nav/nav_styles.css">-->


        <!-- Include Modernizr in the head, before any other Javascript -->
        <script src="includes/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>


        <!-- BootStrap Validator CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"> 

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

                            <br>
                            <form id="html5Form" method="post" action='mail/mail.php'
                                class="form-horizontal"
                                data-bv-message="This value is not valid"
                                data-bv-feedbackicons-valid="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
                                data-bv-feedbackicons-invalid="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
                                data-bv-feedbackicons-validating="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh">    

                              <div class="form-group">
                                      <label>Name</label>
                                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name.." type="text" name="name" id="name"
                                             data-bv-message="The username is not valid"
                                             required data-bv-notempty-message="The username is required and cannot be empty"
                                             pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" data-bv-regexp-message="The username can only consist of alphabetical, number"/>
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label>Email</label>
                                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email.." name="email" id="email" type="email" required data-bv-emailaddress-message="The input is not a valid email address"/>
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Message</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="7" required 
                                data-bv-notempty-message="No empty message"></textarea>
                              </div>  

                                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>
                            </form>

                              <div class="loading">
                                    Sender melding...
                              </div>
                              <div class="success">
                              </div>


        </div>
    </div> <!-- End content -->



    <!-- Include jQuery -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include Mashup -->
    <script src="includes/js/mashup.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <!-- BootStrap Validator JS -->
    <script src="includes/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script> 

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#html5Form').bootstrapValidator();
        });
    </script>       

</body>
</html>
```

**.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        var thisForm = $(this);
        //Prevent the default form action

        //return false;
        e.preventDefault();

        //Hide the form
        $(this).fadeOut(function() {
          //Display the "loading" message
          $(".loading").fadeIn(function() {
            //Post the form to the send script
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: thisForm.attr("action"),
              data: thisForm.serialize(),
              //Wait for a successful response
              success: function(data) {
                //Hide the "loading" message
                $(".loading").fadeOut(function() {
                  //Display the "success" message
                  $(".success").text(data).fadeIn();
                });
              }
            });
          });
        });
      });
  });
```

Comment: Please include the code you're having trouble with in your question, and not just a link to your site. Your site could change over time or go offline, rendering this question pointless for future users.

Comment: @MattD Thank you for your advice. I have now included the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the provided Ajax [example](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/ajax-submit/), it looks like you need to be watching for `.on('success.form.bv')`, not `.on('submit')`.  So you would need to modify your event handler to look like this:

```
$('form').on('success.form.bv', function(e) { ... });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh God, I feel so stupid! Thank you very very much.. it works like a charm ;)